# Getting all users except admins in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I have a users table and roles table, connecting them in many-to-many relationship in role_user table.
I want to get all users except the users that have admin role, I want to include the users that do not have any roles.
Basically all users except admins.
[image]

Comment: Do u need an eloquent query for that?

Answer (score 2):

Add a relation in the User model.

**User.php**

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**For Retrieving**

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function($query){
   $query->where('name', '<>', 'admin') // role with no admin
});
```

**For plain MYSQL**

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN role_user ru ON ru.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ru.role_id WHERE r.name <> 'admin';
```

Comment: This queries users that have at least one role different to an admin role. It will also query admins with additional roles.

Comment: I was unaware of that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Expecting that the relationships are setup properly, this can be achieved rather easily with `whereDoesntHave()`:

```
$roleToExclude = 1;
$users = User::query()
    ->whereDoesntHave('roles', function (Builder $query) use ($roleToExclude) {
        $query->where('id', $roleToExclude);
    })
->get();
```

---

Regarding the comment: if you want to retrieve all users that have at least one role, but their roles may not contain the admin role, then you can use this query:

```
$roleToExclude = 1;
$users = User::query()
    ->has('roles')
    ->whereDoesntHave('roles', function (Builder $query) use ($roleToExclude) {
        $query->where('id', $roleToExclude);
    })
->get();
```

`has('roles')` will ensure there `EXISTS` one role for the user, while `whereDoesntHave('roles', fn())` will ensure it is not an admin role.

---

A note about the suggested edit of @Jino Antony:

When dealing with many-to-many relations, all the `whereX($col, $val)` methods of the query builder operate on the *other table* (`roles` in this case), not the *pivot table* (`role_user`). To query a column on the pivot table, you'd need to use `wherePivot('role_id', $roleToExclude)` in my example.

Comment: Yes. This is a better solution.

Comment: I found how to **solve** it with SQL statement but I need help to convert it to laravel way `SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id FROM role_user WHERE users.id = role_user.user_id AND (role_id = 2 OR role_id = 3)) ORDER BY users.id;`

Comment: This is the more complex query of what I've suggested _if there are exactly 3 roles with the IDs 1, 2 and 3 where 1 is the 'admin' role_. Using this query, you'll have to adjust the `WHERE` clauses whenever you add new roles - with my version, you don't. But to be fair, my query will also return users without any roles - your's will return users with at least one role of id `2` or `3`. This can be achieved easier though. See my edit.

Comment: **Thanks** It solved by using this `$users = User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function($query){
            $query->where('name','admin')->orWhere('name', 'root');
        })->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Since Above Answers are missing the Reverse Method i have added that Relation

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

 //roles that need to be excuded
 //it also accepts the array
 $rolesExcept = 'admin';

 //roles that need to be included
 //it also accepts the array
 $rolesOnly =  'admin';

 //closure that filter the the rolesOnly
 $withSpecificRolesClosure = function ($query) use ( $rolesOnly) 
 {
   $query-> whereIn( 'name', (array) $rolesOnly); // role with  only admin
 };

 //closure that filter the the rolesExcept
 $withOutSpecificRolesClosure = function ($query) use ( $rolesExcept) 
 {
    $query->whereNotIn('name', (array)$rolesExcept); // role with no admin
 };

 //get all the users with the role with admim
 $userWithRoleAdmin = App\Models\User::whereHas('roles', $withSpecificRolesClosure)->get();

 //get all the users with the role without admim
 $userWithOutRoleAdmin = App\Models\User::whereHas('roles',$withOutSpecificRolesClosure)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one. if you're not using a model relationship this would work

```
$users = DB::table(role_user as ru')
                ->join('users as u', 'ru.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
                ->join('roles as r', 'r.id', '=', 'ru.id')
                ->where('r.name', '<>', 'admin')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', Role::ROLE_ADMIN);
})->get();
```

add relationship code in User.php file.

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```