# How to get all users with all their roles in a many to many relation based sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**Goal**
Get all users with all their roles.

**Problem**
If one user has more than one role, i get an instance of this user for each role he has.

**Description**
I have a setup with three tables, like it is described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801506/getting-all-users-except-admins-in-many-to-many-relationship) for example.
A `user` table, a `role` table and a `role_user` table.
Now i want to query all users with their roles with this query:

```
$allUsers = DB::table('users')
            ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users' . '.id')
            ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
            ->select(['users.uuid', 'users.username', 'users.last_online_at', 'roles.role', 'roles.id as role_id'])
            ->get();
```

To me it looks exactly like the plain MYSQL query proposal which made Lizesh Shakya in the second post of the stackoverflow post i already mentioned above.
Except for the fact that i use Laravel. And i know, that i could solve it with the user model with the appropriate `belongsToMany`methods are set in it and the roles model. But i want to understand it a bit deeper and therefore i try it that way.
If i have three users and if one user has the roles "editor" and "author" for example, the query returns four users. For each role one.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1267 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#1273 ▼
      +"uuid": "fc8bbd29-9005-4f05-9706-a437933d3bc2"
      +"username": "admin"
      +"last_online_at": "2021-01-16 19:01:37"
      +"role": "admin"
      +"role_id": 1
    }
    1 => {#1272 ▼
      +"uuid": "d957e5af-f8f3-4a07-a2c3-eabecbdda618"
      +"username": "author1"
      +"last_online_at": "2021-01-16 19:01:37"
      +"role": "author"
      +"role_id": 3
    }
    2 => {#1282 ▼
      +"uuid": "dc94d900-bbaf-4605-b8d8-6bab5fb43b70"
      +"username": "editor"
      +"last_online_at": "2021-01-16 19:01:37"
      +"role": "editor"
      +"role_id": 2
    }
    3 => {#1281 ▼
      +"uuid": "d957e5af-f8f3-4a07-a2c3-eabecbdda618"
      +"username": "author1"
      +"last_online_at": "2021-01-16 19:01:37"
      +"role": "editor"
      +"role_id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

So where is my fault? :)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that this is the result of the query and nothing else? Query looks good to me and I would also expect just one user since both joins should be inner joins

Comment: Why are you going for the joins when instead you can use relationship which is like ABC?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes, thats the result of the query. Directly after the lines i made a `dd(@allUsers)`
@Ahmad Karimi i dont understand, what you mean. I have this setup because one user could have more than one role.

Comment: I believe what Ahmad tried to ask is why you don't use [the built in functions for a one to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: @leonp5 have you added the relationship between in the models?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes i have `public function users(): BelongsToMany {
return $this->belongsToMany(Leonp5\Limplecms\Models\User::class); }`
in the role model and `public function roles(): BelongsToMany { return this->belongsToMany('Leonp5\Limplecms\Models\Role'); }` in the user model.
But does this matter for a query without using models?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly yo want a list of users with their roles right?

On your UserController:

```php
   public function getUsersWithRoles(){
         $all_users = User::all()->load('roles');

         $body = compact('all_users');   
        
         return response()->json(compact('body')); 
   }
```

OR

```php
   public function getUsersWithRoles(){
         $all_users = User::with('roles')->get();

         $body = compact('all_users');   
        
         return response()->json(compact('body')); 
   }
```

Don't forget to declare your relations in the models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as i wrote, i wanna try it wihtout the modles with plain MySQL queries.