# Laravel @can method does not work for all roles

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**Problem**

The user with the role "author" doesnt see the HTML inside the `@can ... endcan` block.

**Description**
Developing a Laravel package and restrict the navbar accordingly to the roles. But when i try to make a nav element only for a user with the role "author", it doesnt work. When i replace "author" with another role, it works.
Maybe my approach is too complicated and proposals for other approaches are welcome as well as hints, where i have to look for solving the problem.
I have a "standard" setup with three tables. One for users, one for roles and one for role_user relations (as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801506/getting-all-users-except-admins-in-many-to-many-relationship)). The relations in the models are set.
You can find the whole project [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/limplecms/-/tree/usermanagement3).
Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
@can('author')
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"
                            href="{{ route('pages.index') }}">{{ __('limplecms::navigation.pages.overview')}}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endcan
                    @canany(['admin', 'editor'])
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ __('limplecms::navigation.pages')}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('pages.index') }}">
                                {{__('limplecms::navigation.pages.overview')}}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('pages.create') }}">
                                {{__('limplecms::navigation.pages.create')}}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    @endcanany
                    @can('admin')
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ __('limplecms::navigation.user.management')}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('users.index') }}">
                                {{__('limplecms::navigation.users.overview')}}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('users.create') }}">
                                {{__('limplecms::navigation.users.create')}}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    @endcan
```

Comment: you setup gates in the authorization system for roles?

Comment: Yes man! Thanks. The gate for the author was missing in the package provider.
Write it as an answer so i can check it :)

Comment: i would probably not use the authorization system and use something like `@hasRole(...)` type of thing

Comment: @hasRole is an native Laravel function or you mean I should write it by my own?

Comment: you would have to create a blade directive, but just an idea

Comment: Alright, I'll take it in consideration :)

Comment: Instead of creating my own role and permission concept I always use laravel-permission package which provides middlewares as well gates. URL - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission